# Multiple routes with different parameters filter to a single endopoint with Zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to build an api gateway on top of an old Solr server with zuul.

I want to have multiple routes such as :

```
api-zuul/api1
api-zuul/api2
api-zuul/api3
```

redirecteing to the same endpoint (Solr api) but passing different parameters depending on the call.

```
api-zuul/api1 => mysolrserver/api/select?&collection=api1&otherParams
api-zuul/api2 => mysolrserver/api/select?&collection=api2&otherParams
api-zuul/api3 => mysolrserver/api/select?&collection=api3&otherParams
```

At the moment i manage to pass parameters via a ZuulFilter to only one route:

```
    public class ProjectParamFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectBodyFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> paramAll = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> paramTrue = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> paramJson = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> paramCollection = new ArrayList<>();

        paramAll.add("*:*");
        paramTrue.add("true");
        paramJson.add("json");
        paramCollection.add("Project");

        params.put("q", paramAll);
        params.put("indent", paramTrue);
        params.put("wt", paramJson);
        params.put("collection", paramCollection);

        ctx.setRequestQueryParams(params);

        log.info("passed params :" + ctx.getRequestQueryParams().toString());
        log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how i can call different filters for the same endpoint depending on the incoming request since zuul is designed to handle multiple services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone come across the same issue, i solved it using the shouldFilter() function.

Add a route in application.properties :

```
zuul.routes.test.url = https://stackoverflow.com/
```

In the filter :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {

    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    if (ctx.getRequest().getRequestURI().equals("/test")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```